# Problem with basic central limit theorem

Tags: statistics

I can't make sense of this very basic problem

A manufacturing process has the expected time of 200 min and standard deviation of 10 min. The reset of the process has the expected time of 30 min with standard deviation of 3 min.

What is the probability that the sum of the times is no more than 260min?

Now, using the central limit theorem I thought it would be: $(260-210)/13$.

According to the answer it is $(260-210)/\sqrt{100+9}$

This doesn't make sense to me, why would I want to calculate the square root of the combined variances when I already have the individual standard deviations?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: This does not involve the central limit theorem at all. The central limit theorem is about a sum or an average of a large number of random variables; specifically about what the distribution approaches as the number of random variables grows. This is about a sum of only two random variables, so it does not involve the CLT.

Comment: The fact stated in the initial sentence of the answer posted by Ian is the reason why mean squared deviations (variances) and root-mean-square deviations (i.e. standard deviations) instead of mean absolute deviations, which are the more obvious thing to use.

Answer (score 2):

For independent random variables, variances add, not standard deviations. So you sum the variances to get the variance of the sum and then take the square root to get the standard deviation of the sum.

If standard deviations added, then sample averages wouldn't concentrate around the average of the underlying distribution. You should think about why that is.

(Also, what you're writing are just $z$ scores, not probabilities.)